# sphinx:No content update in html content from docstring

Tags: python-sphinx

I have been working on a project on to interface with Senna which is tool used in NLP processing using Python. For easy generation of documentation I followed reStructuredText documentation style which is pretty easy one.

On calling `make html`, few time(and sometime no warning) there has been shown warning like

> docstring of pntl.tools.Annotator.test:2: WARNING: Field list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent and one more thing what is the use of this number 2 displayed in the working.

```
def test(senna_path="/media/jawahar/jon/ubuntu/senna", sent="", dep_model="", batch=False, 
           jar_path="/media/jawahar/jon/ubuntu/practNLPTools-lite/pntl"):
    """please replace the path of yours environment(accouding to OS path)
    :parama str senna_path: path for senna location
    :parama str dep_model: stanford dependency parser model location
    :parama str or list sent: the sentense to process with Senna
    :parama bool batch: makeing as batch process with one or more sentense passing
    :parama str jar_path: location of stanford-parser.jar file
    """
```

and Image of the  [built result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKF7x.png) is been attach to show error in the content of html. For detail view of my project follow this [link](https://github.com/jawahar273/practNLPTools-lite/blob/master/pntl/tools.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you have incorrect syntax, specifically no blank lines around the description and the field list, and indentation is not correct. White space matters.

Spelling matters, too. You probably meant `:param blah blah: thing` not `:parama blah blah: thing:`

See [Info field lists](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#info-field-lists) for more information.

**Edit**

The following example should fix the issue. Note the correct spelling of "param", and the necessary line break separating the parameter list from the description in the docstring. Additionally, to avoid PEP8 warnings in your code (reStructuredText does not really care in this case), you should wrap long lines as noted in the method definition. There is another new line wrapping in the parameter list so that Sphinx will render it correctly as well as avoid the PEP8 warning.

```
def test(senna_path="/media/jawahar/jon/ubuntu/senna", sent="", dep_model="",
         batch=False,
         jar_path="/media/jawahar/jon/ubuntu/practNLPTools-lite/pntl"):
    """
    please replace the path of yours environment(accouding to OS path)

    :param str senna_path: path for senna location
    :param str dep_model: stanford dependency parser model location
    :param str or list sent: the sentense to process with Senna
    :param bool batch: makeing as batch process with one or more sentense
                       passing
    :param str jar_path: location of stanford-parser.jar file
    """
```

Comment: I am kind of new Sphinx so pls correct me the above doc string into correct format and display them in the answer. It will be great to know **visualize what the mistake I have done**.